# setenv/unsetenv C stdlib Mingw64

Tags: c, std, mingw-w64

I'm compiling with Mingw64 and it comes unsetenv function doesn't exist in stdlib.
I found setenv is equivalent to putenv, what about unsetenv ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There might not be anything. What do you need it for?

Comment: Note that `putenv()` is not exactly equivalent to `setenv()`.  `putenv()` uses the string you pass to it as the value in the environment; it must be a string with a long lifetime (e.g. global scope, or dynamically allocated with `malloc()`).  By contrast, `setenv()` makes a copy or the data it is passed – so you don't have to ensure that the arguments to `setenv()` will not not change after calling the function.  The `setenv()` and `unsetenv()` pair a much better.

Comment: `unsetenv()` is in POSIX. So it should be available in libc on any POSIX-conformant system.

Comment: @Barmar `unsetenv()` didn't appear until POSIX 6, so the ability to remove an environment isn't critical functionalty.  Given the `exec*()` functions in POSIX all provide variations for the calling program to specify the exact environment passed to child functions, even allowing the caller to create an entire environment for the child separate from the parent environment, `unsetenv()` is effectively a convenience function and not strictly necessary.  Given MINGW is for Windows and Windows isn't POSIX, `unsetenv()` might not be available.

Comment: @AndrewHenle By that logic, `setenv()` and `putenv()` are also just conveniences.

Comment: And the documentation says it was in POSIX.1-2001. That's over 20 years, it's not unreasonable to expect most environments to conform by now.

Comment: @Barmar Windows isn't POSIX so I'd say it is unreasonable to expect them to exist there.  OP is specifically asking about Windows, albeit Mingw on Windows.

Comment: I want to compile a code which use ``setenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS",param,1)`` and ``unsetenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS")``

Comment: Change it to use `omp_set_num_threads` instead?